# Issue with KSQL STRUCT with VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'

Tags: json, apache-kafka, ksqldb

Unable to create KSQL Stream with `STRUCT` with the following data

```
{ 
  "_id": {"$oid": "62d79f3f63000ed99fa46f27"}, 
  "CustomerID": "TT-21070", 
  "CustomerName": "TedTrevino", 
  "Segment": "Consumer", 
  "Country": "UnitedStates", 
  "City": "Akron", 
  "State": "Ohio", 
  "PostalCode": 44312, 
  "Region": "East"
}
```

Here is the Topic

```
ksql> print 'Mongo.Sample_SuperStore.People' from beginning;
Key format: JSON or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format:  does not match any supported format. It may be a STRING with encoding other than UTF8, or some other format.
rowtime: 2022/07/20 07:33:55.826 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"_id\": {\"_data\": \"8262D7AFE0000000072B022C0100296E5A1004308C1145AA9245EB958ACBB9EA8ECEDF46645F6964006462D7AFE063000ED99FA470D00004\"}}"}, value: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\x5C"_id\x5C": {\x5C"$oid\x5C": \x5C"62d7afe063000ed99fa470d0\x5C"}, \x5C"CustomerID\x5C": \x5C"SM-20320\x5C", \x5C"CustomerName\x5C": \x5C"SeanMiller\x5C", \x5C"Segment\x5C": \x5C"HomeOffice\x5C", \x5C"Country\x5C": \x5C"UnitedStates\x5C", \x5C"City\x5C": \x5C"Jacksonville\x5C", \x5C"State\x5C": \x5C"Florida\x5C", \x5C"PostalCode\x5C": 32216, \x5C"Region\x5C": \x5C"South\x5C"}"}, partition: 0
```

Then created this Stream as below

```
CREATE STREAM STREAM_SUPERSTORE_PEOPLE (
payload STRUCT< \
      _id STRUCT<`$oid` VARCHAR>, \
      CustomerID VARCHAR, \
      CustomerName VARCHAR, \
      Segment VARCHAR, \
      Country VARCHAR, \
      City VARCHAR, \
      State VARCHAR, \
      PostalCode INT, \
      Region VARCHAR> \
) \
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='Mongo.Sample_SuperStore.People', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Output is blank

```
ksql> select * from STREAM_SUPERSTORE_PEOPLE emit changes;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|PAYLOAD                                                                                                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But following way with Type `VARCHAR` instead of `STRUCT` is working

```
CREATE STREAM STREAM_SUPERSTORE_PEOPLE (payload varchar)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='Mongo.Sample_SuperStore.People', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

```
## Extracting field one by one from PAYLOAD
SELECT 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.CustomerID') as CustomerID,
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.CustomerName') as CustomerName,
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.Segment') as Segment,
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.Country') as Country,
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.City') as City,
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.State') as State,
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.PostalCode') as PostalCode,
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.Region') as Region from STREAM_SUPERSTORE_PEOPLE 
emit changes limit 1;
```

Output

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|CUSTOMERID     |CUSTOMERNAME   |SEGMENT        |COUNTRY        |CITY           |STATE          |POSTALCODE     |REGION         |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|TT-21070       |TedTrevino     |Consumer       |UnitedStates   |Akron          |Ohio           |44312          |East           |
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

I want to do with the `STRUCT` way. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted is not your actual data in the topic. Look at the error output, and you see `{"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"_id\": ...`, so your inner-JSON is just a string, explaining why you needed `EXTRACTJSONFIELD` function.

In other words, the data in your topic may look like JSON, but it is not properly formatted to use STRUCT `VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'`.

You need to fix Kafka Connector (?) to use `JSONConverter` with **`schemas.enable=false`** to get records **without** `schema` and `payload` fields.